# How do I detect the language using node alias

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I know to get the current language of a website:

```
$current_lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
```

However, given that I have a node alias

```
$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$nid);
```

How do I get the language of that `$alias` node?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me: You can't get a translated alias without LanguageManager, so just use the exact code you posted yourself in code line 1. [AliasManager is doing the same](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Path%21AliasManager.php/function/AliasManager%3A%3AgetAliasByPath/8.2.x).

Answer (score 1):

To get the path alias of specific language try with:

```
$current_lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManager $aliasManager */
$aliasManager =  \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager');
$alias = $aliasManager->getAliasByPath('/node/10', $current_lang);
```

If you want to get the language code from alias try with:

```
$aliasArray = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->load(['source' => '/node/' . $nid]);
$lang_code = $aliasArray['langcode'];
```